# Batch file equivalent of CURRENTDIR="$PWD"?

Tags: shell, batch-file

I'm trying to translate a *very simple* (Unix) shell script into a "batch file".  I have most of it down, except for the line

```
CURRENTDIR="$PWD"
```

How can I translate this to "batchese"?

Thanks!

Comment: `$PWD` means _The current working directory as set by the `cd` command._

Answer (score 56):

The simplest form:

```
SET CURRENTDIR="%cd%"
```

Comment: Also, if you want the actual directory of your batch file: set dir="%~dp0"

Comment: What is the difference between set dir="%~dp0" and SET CURRENTDIR="%cd%"?

Comment: @DanielDropik `%~dp0` means: directory and path (dp) of the argument 0 (the full pathname of the script file) - therefore always the directory of the running script. `%cd%` on the other hand is the _current directory_. The current directory may change, for example when using the `cd` command (`cd ..` will change the current directory to its parent directory). Those are completely different things.