# How can my batch file find its own location and call a matlab script inside that folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have an internal software that generates folders with batch files. The batch file is supposed to run a matlab file in the same folder, but in fact it just runs Matlab and the previous Matlab script (not the one in its folder).
I need a command in my batch file to recognize its own location(folder) and run the matlab file from the same folder.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456801/batch-file-equivalent-of-currentdir-pwd).

Comment: the software generates my matlab script and batch file in the same folder:
here is the command I have:

call command prompt
set "batchisin=%~dp0
 "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe" -automation -r myMatlabFile

Comment: Hey! you've figured it out yourself :) (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the %0 parameter. This on is an implicit parameter that you do not pass to the scrip

try this and see if it helps you get going:

```
@echo %~dp0
```

the ~dp sequence strips the name and extension from the full path to the script.

*note that this works only from within a script, not from the command prompt*

References: for-command

Comment: I also tried this but didn't help. 

call command prompt
SET CURRENTDIR="%cd%" 
 "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe" -automation -r "run('CURRENTDIR\myMatlabFile.m')"

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're looking for. Did the command in my answer emit the expected path? If so i would simply pushd to this folder (pushd %~dp0) then call the matlab-app with only the filename as argument to run and pop back after the call (popd)

Comment: Thank you. It now works with %cd%

SET CURRENTDIR="%cd%" 
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe" -automation -r "run('%cd%\myMatlabFile.m')"